# Django: Check if user have added a new instance in the form?

Tags: python, django, models

I have a form, which i am rendering. It also allow user to add a new instance if it does not exist in the list.
lets say the field is `name` from `category` modal.

`name` is an drop down list, and if user does not find his value in the list, he writes the `name` in the next input box.

When i validate it, it fails. because its not an instance of `category`. 
Then I got it by using `self.data` and i compare if its an Integer, or not?

If its an integer, than its simply an existing element, if not, the user might have chosen a new User, and thus by getting it from the `self.data`, i can create the 
 `category`

object and save it and replace the original value with the ID so that validation does not fail.

Problem.

I know using `self.data` and using it for a db query can be dangerous. As user is allowed to input anything in it, and it might empty my database with that query, (i have heard it like that). Is this really possible? if yes, how to avoid that.

Hope someone can give me an idea.

Comment: You should do this validation/assignment in the clean() method of your form. If you post the relevant bits of your form class, I can show you what the clean() method should do.

Comment: @DavidM when we send a proper value from the form dropdown, I definatly get that in the clean method under `self.cleaned_data` but what if the user does not find that value in the dropdown and clicks add new? and text box appears, and user writes the value and submits it with the forms. now in clean, i do not get this value in `self.cleaned_data` but rather in `self.clean`. I have a fear that if i get the value from the self.clean i may end us messing with the database if some suspicious user enters dangerous string in it. Is this possible?

Comment: I've added an answer. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your form has a `name` field for existing category names and a `new_name` field for the input box. In your form's `clean()` method, you'll want to check to see if `self.cleaned_data` has a value for `new_name` and act accordingly. You might do:

```
self.cleaned_data['name'] = self.cleaned_data['new_name']
```

for example.

Unless you override other field or form methods, the data in these fields are 'safe' as far as malicious input is concerned. If you raise a `ValidationError` in the form's `clean()` method, `is_valid()` will return false. So, as long as you:

```
form = YourForm(...)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

The `save()` will not be called with invalid data.

Comment: I am perfectly sure about you are trying to say. when the user enter next value in the text box, it comes with the same field name. i.e. `name`. so the cleaned_data does not contain the textual name field as it is Foregoing key with category. i can access this value from self.data, but cleaned_data does not have this value. cleaned_data only have values that are passed from the validation. I am concerned about malicious input if user input and i get it from self.data :(

Comment: I am guessing you are using the same "name" attribute for both the drop down list and the text field. If that is true, I suggest you do not do that and instead use a new field for the text field with a different name. If you post your form class definition, I can show you what to do there.

Comment: Ok, I will try to use a different field. but how to ensure that user have not entered some malicious string in the input?

Comment: Generally, if you're using Django forms the way they are intended to be used, you're pretty safe. More details won't fit here, but Django has great documentation. If you want to be sure, post your code (probably in a new question) and just ask.